Google Sheets, connect checkboxes with data
link to file
In sheet1 I insert data and I need it to be in the same order as I inserted them.
In sheet2 I want to data be sorted by goal date, and I can check the checkbox.
The problem is that if I insert data to sheet1 which goes between in sheet2, checkboxes doesn't move, and now checkbox is behind wrong row.
Only code I use here is Sort function in sheet2 B2 to get data from sheet1:
=SORT(sheet1!B2:C,2,TRUE)

Is there way to bind checkboxes with data so they move with corresponding row?
link to file
Thanks

Can you clarify what do you mean by: if they are completed? - also, [edit] and add the code you're using.

You are describing how formula results get misaligned with manually entered data. There is no turn-key solution to work around the issue. It would probably be a good idea to rethink your spreadsheet structure so that data that belongs together is all in the same tab.
Lance has given a thorough treatment of the row misalignment issue and how it can be dealt with in some cases.

Thanks, this almost solved my problem but it requires Data > Create a Filter, which is not best, i would need data to refresh automatically but Data > Create a Filter needs refresh.
It has to do for now but if there's more dynamic solution, i would love to hear about it.

There is no turnkey solution. See Lance's write-up to understand why.

I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer but it has been extremely useful! Lance's solution, combined with some apps script automatisation (applying new filter onEdit) has solved my problem. Thanks!
